# Objective-c reload tableview from another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am super confused.

I have 2 controllers, lets call them controller1 and controller2.

In controller1.m I have this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

and in controller2.m I am trying to reload the tableview in controller1.m:

```
- (void)GetRequest
{

    NSArray *tableData = [dataSource.areaData GetPurchaseOrderItems:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",areaPickerSelectionString,unitPickerSelectionString]];

    if(!purchaseOrder.objects){
        purchaseOrder.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < [tableData count]; i++){
        [purchaseOrder.objects addObjectsFromArray:[tableData objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[tableData objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [purchaseOrder.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    NSLog(@"%@", purchaseOrder.objects);

    //[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I have tried the following:

controller1.h:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
```

controller1.m:

```
@synthesize tableView;
```

controller2.h:

```
#import "controller1.h"

@interface controller2 ()
{


    controller1 *purchaseOrder;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     purchaseOrder = [[controller1 alloc]init];
}
```

and then `[purchaseOrder.tableView reloadData];`

and my tableView doesnt get reloaded. WTF ? I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I also get this warning on:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and here is the warning:

```
Local declaration of 'tableView' hides instance variable
```

Comment: There seems to be another variable name 'tableView'. You need to rename it or make sure you're targeting the right one. Please show more code to check that.

Comment: There are a bunch of things odd about this but let's start with `purchaseOrder = [[controller1 alloc]init];`.  This creates a **new** `controller1`.  If you want `purchaseOrder` to update, you need to push or present it first.  I suspect you probably already have a `controller1` somewhere else but this new one has no relationship to any that might have already been on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to `controller1` within `controller2`. In Controller2.h, declare a `controller1` property.

```
#import "Controller1.h"
@interface Controller2 : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) Controller1 *controller1;
@end
```

I am going to make the assumption that `controller1` is segueing to `controller2`. So you can pass the reference of `controller1` to `controller2` in `prepareForSegue`. Be sure to `#import Controller2.h` in Controller1.m. In Controller1.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryBoardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[Controller2 class]]) {
        Controller2 *controller2 = (Controller2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller2.controller1 = self;  // now you can reference the tableView in controller2
    }  
}
```

Now in Controller2.m, you can reload the table view where you like.

```
- (void)GetRequest
{
    // ...
    [self.controller1.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what I am suppose to put in the prepareForSegue (after the ...)

Comment: It is a method that controller1 inherits from UIViewController. I couldn't remember the actual syntax so I copped out and put ... Start typing "- prepareFor" in controller1 and autocomplete should fill the rest out for you.

Comment: Edited my answer to fill out the method name.

Comment: I get 3 errors with your code: 1. Expected a type in the prepareForSegue method, 2. destinationController not found on object type '__strong id' and 3 Property controller1 not found on object type controller2

Comment: 1. Cast the destinationViewController to Controller2.   2. It is destinationViewController instead of destinationController. Also, it looks like you did sender.DestinationViewController when it should be segue.destinationViewController.    3. Make sure to #import the header to Controller2 in order to see the controller1 property that we added.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, can you update your answer please so its clear?

Comment: Updated to include more detail.